# How to find /dev/ name of USB Device for Serial Reading on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, serial-port, embedded, putty

I am trying to plug in a device into my Macbook and connect to it to read it's serial port. I know the device connects on baudrate 115200.

Currently, I run the command

`ioreg -p IOUSB -l -b | grep -E "@|PortNum|USB Serial Number"`

I can see the embedded device plugged in

```
+-o Root Hub Simulation Simulation@14000000
| +-o iBridge@14200000
| |     "PortNum" = 2
| +-o USB2.0 Hub@14100000
|   |   "PortNum" = 1
|   +-o 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub@14120000 
|   | |   "PortNum" = 2
|   | +-o MBED CMSIS-DAP@14122000
|   |       "PortNum" = 2
|   |       "USB Serial Number" = "024002267822ce0a00000000000000000000000085fb33b2"
|   +-o USB Keyboard           @14110000 
|         "PortNum" = 1
|         "USB Serial Number" = "0000000000000001"
```

**note:** There's a tag close to

`<class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100014343, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (363 ms), retain 33>`

next to every device's name above, but I removed them for formatting issues (as I don't think they're related to the question). In the event they are, that is the tag for my embedded device).

**The Question**

How would I find out the MBED device's association in /dev/?

I am trying to find the device `MBED CMSIS-DAP@14122000` inside the /dev/ directory, so that I can read its serial output. This is where I am lost.

The end goal is that I could use `screen` or `putty` or something similar to:

`screen /dev/ttyTHIS_MBED_DEVICE 115200`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

So, I actually found the answer.

To find out what the device name is, I did an `ls` of the `/dev/` directory with the device plugged in and then with it disconnected.

```
ls -lha /dev/tty* > plugged.txt
ls -lha /dev/tty* > np.txt
```

Then I compared the files using

```
vimdiff plugged.txt np.txt
```

And saw the line

`crw-rw-rw-  1 root             wheel   19,  30 Jan 16 15:24 /dev/tty.usbmodem145222`

Sure enough, the device is named `tty.usbmodem145222`!

Comment: Right! Don't forget to use `-a` in your ls !

Comment: Please help me it is giving me this output: `+ +--133 lines: crw-rw-rw-  1 root         wheel    2,   0 Feb 19 21:43 /dev/tty---------------------|+ +--133 lines: crw-rw-rw-  1 root         wheel    2,   0 Feb 19 21:43 /dev/tty--------------------`

Comment: @Joshua use `diff plugged.txt np.txt | less` instead

Answer (score 14):

Please try

```
ls /dev/tty* | grep usb
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer when running MacOS 14.3 on M2 Apple Processor

I was able to run `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` on the command line and find my device.

> FT232R USB UART:
> Product ID: 0x6001
> Vendor ID: 0x0403  (Future Technology Devices International Limited)
> Version: 6.00
> Serial Number: AB0O4KAS
> Speed: Up to 12 Mb/s
> Manufacturer: FTDI
> Location ID: 0x01110000 / 4
> Current Available (mA): 500
> Current Required (mA): 90
> Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

Then running `ls -lha /dev/ | grep AB0O4KAS` (the serial number) gave me the device name:

> tty.usbserial-AB0O4KAS